# Conversion of Date-Time Formats

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I have a column in my `dataframe` in the format : `15-Feb-2020 19:09:34`

and

I want to convert it into : `2020-02-15` ie `YYYY-MM-DD` using `python`.

Is there a way of doing this using `datetime` or any other python module?

Answer (score 1):

Use the to_datetime pandas function.

Like this, maybe:

```
import pandas as pd
#if DATE is the column with datetime values then
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

This will convert the column to the form of YYYY-MM-DD .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_datetime` function and after conversion choose only `date`

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                   Date
0  15-Feb-2020 19:09:34

In [13]: df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                   Date    new_date
0  15-Feb-2020 19:09:34  2020-02-15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `datetime` module to format.

```
from datetime import datetime

#current date and time
now = datetime.now()
#date and time format: dd/mm/YYYY H:M:S
format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
#format datetime using strftime()
time1 = now.strftime(format)

print("Formatted DateTime:", time1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a date string to another one by parsing and reformating as below.

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('15-Feb-2020 19:09:34', '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')

print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

You can find related format codes here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes